# How to index a 3x3 subblock of a 9x9 Sudoku board

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, sudoku

I'm working on a Sudoku solver (for a Leet problem) and I'm able to manipulate the 9 x 9 array of numbers in terms of rows and columns pretty easily using basic indexing, e.g.,
`board[row,:]` or `board[:,col]`.   Each of these slices a 1D array from the 2D array.

I'd like to do the equivalent for the 3 x 3 subblocks of a Sudoku board, in the following sense.  I'd like to define a Python function `iBlock` that takes as argument the block row and block column numbers, and returns *something* such that `board[something]` addresses the 9 elements of a subblock such that `board[something]` could be used as follows:

```
board[something] = [ 3, 7, 2, 1, 4, 5, 9, 8, 6 ]
```

would have the effect of transforming the full 9 x 9 board from

```
. . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . .
. . . - - - . . .
. . . - - - . . .
. . . - - - . . .
. . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . .
```

to:

```
. . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . .
. . . 3 7 2 . . .
. . . 1 4 5 . . .
. . . 9 8 6 . . .
. . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . .
```

and I'd like to be able to use `board[something]` on the rhs of an assignment as well.

So the question is... what is *something* so that things would work as above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopfully this information helps. I would use [numpy and slicing](https://www.w3schools.com/python/numpy/numpy_array_slicing.asp).

Here is a small example that hopefully produces your desired results:

```py
import numpy as np

mat = np.zeros((9,9))
start = 3
end = 6
mat[start:end,start:end] = np.array([ 3, 7, 2, 1, 4, 5, 9, 8, 6 ]).reshape((3,3))

print(mat)
```

```sh
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 3. 7. 2. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 4. 5. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 9. 8. 6. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Noodling around, I think I found the solution:

```
def iBlock( R, C ):
    return ( [3*R,3*R,3*R,3*R+1,3*R+1,3*R+1,3*R+2,3*R+2,3*R+2],
             [3*C,3*C+1,3*C+2,3*C,3*C+1,3*C+2,3*C,3*C+1,3*C+2] )
iBlock(1,2)
=> ([3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5], [6, 7, 8, 6, 7, 8, 6, 7, 8])

a = np.zeros((9,9))
a[ iBlock(1,2) ] = range(1,10)

a =>
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 2., 3.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 4., 5., 6.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 7., 8., 9.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```